# Stopping MapView's subviews from propagating touches

Tags: uiview, touch, mkmapview

When I add a subview to a MKMapView or to any of it's descendent views, touches will pass right through and affect the map.

This question is ultimately used to explain a bug that was fixed for my custom callout which adds a view to an annotation view. The callout is not to be dismissed when the callout is touched and this question is in reference to that. But for the case brevity I'll use a smaller example that demonstrates the problem.

Setting exclusiveTouch and userInteractionEnabled doesn't do anything. BTW.

Let's take a UIView and attach it to the mapView

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[mapView addSubview:view];
```

And let's add a gesture to the map as well

```
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)]];
```

And just have handleLongPress print something NSLog(@"longpress"); Now run the program and observe how long pressing the black uiview will cause the longPress to be triggered. If we add an annotation that shows a callout and select it, touching the black uiview will dismiss it. And if we scroll the map so that the annotation is under the black uiview, we'll be able to select the annotation. Now here's my solution. We tag the view that we're going to add to mapview with SOME_TAG and overwrite the hitTest method for MKMapView

```
@interface MKMapView(HackySolution)

@end

@implementation MKMapView(HackySolution)
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    // block touch propagation
    if(view.tag == SOME_TAG){
        view = nil;
    }

    return view;
}

@end
```

Now here's the deal, I may have solved my problem, but I really don't know why touches from the UIView are being passed right through onto the map. It doesn't make sense for a touch to a subview to be passed onto it's parentView. Maybe I'm not understanding how touches work. I mean if I place a button on a normal UIView and place another uiview on top of it, completely obscuring it, the button wouldn't get the touch right? I'm starting to second guess myself. :/

I can only guess that MKMapView is wired to do this, but I'm unsure. I thought there was a scroll view somewhere within MKMapView, but I ran through all the subviews and all the descendents and didn't find anything.

Is there a better way to solve this problem or is this the best it gets?

Any insight into the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got the exact same problem here. I noticed a difference when I add my view in a UIButton and the UIButton is added to the annotation view (then it works as expected). When I add the UIView with a gesture recognizer, the recognizer does send me the touch, but then the map gets it as well and fires a didDeselect. How did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: As you can see this happened a while ago. And since there was no response I stuck to my hackySolution as shown above.

Comment: Ok good to know thank you. I confirm that it works when the view is wrapped in a UIButton (although it is slower, really don't understand why). I think there is a bug somewhere...

Comment: Hmmmm, have you used instruments to figure out what's taking up all the cpu time?

Comment: I have no idea how to use instruments to get that information... Any hint?

Comment: It's not that hard at all. There's a bunch of people on the internet that do it far better than me. Here's one of them,

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments--mobile-9403  The gist is that you run your software, do some things and you can see who's hogging up your CPU time. Check it out. It's good for figuring out what's making your app choppy.